# QGIS 3.4.2 SQL Permissions

Tags: qgis

In the QGIS Browser, is there a way to restrict table deletions/truncations without doing this through SQL Server permissions? As a GIS admin if I want to remove a layer from the map it is too easy to accidentally right click on the feature class in the browser instead, as I have almost deleted a SQL feature class instead of removing the layer. Other GIS users will have this restricted through SQL Permissions.

Comment: Same. I don't know why QGIS has this ability built in. However, setting user permissions at the DB level will limit what a user can do in QGIS (ie. deleting, etc.).